# O que ocorre internamente na execução de uma aplicação Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Recentemente venho estudando Spring Boot, eu queria saber o que ocorre internamente quando uma aplicação é iniciada, pois todo projeto tem uma classe principal que vem sempre anotada com `@SpringBootApplication`. Qual o propósito dessa anotação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De maneira geral, o Spring Boot se preocupa com 3 coisas principais em sua inicialização:

1) Configurar automaticamente o seu projeto a partir das dependências que você declara no sistema de build (pom.xml - Maven ou build.gradle - Gradle) sobre o qual seu projeto é construído. Isso é feito pela anotação **`@EnableAutoConfiguration`**.

2) Varrer o seu projeto em busca de classes que possuam certas anotações específicas (como `@Service` ou `@Repository`, por exemplo), que informem que essas classes devem ter seu ciclo de vida gerenciado pelo Spring. Essas classes são os *beans* e o fruto desse gerenciamento nada mais é do que a injeção de dependência (o `@Autowired` que você certamente já viu). O ato de varrer é disparado pela anotação **`@ComponentScan`**.

3) Definir que a própria classe que contém o método `main` seja ela mesma um *bean*, anotando-a com **`@Configuration`**. Por quê? Para permitir que você possa, caso queria, ter outros *beans* (já previamente escaneados pelo item 2) injetados nessa classe, poupando você da necessidade de criar classes adicionais para isso. Lembrando que só uma classe *bean* (ou seja, gerenciada pelo Spring) pode ter injetados nela outros *beans*.

Pois bem, para conveniência, em vez de você anotar sua classe com as 3 anotações em negrito, basta você anotá-la com **`@SpringBootApplication`**, que obterá o mesmo efeito, com as configurações padrão do Spring Boot.

Estendendo um pouco sua pergunta: mas, por que há o método `main()`? Para permitir que sua aplicação rode como uma aplicação Java comum, que, como sabemos, é iniciada a partir de um método `main()`. Como um programa Spring Boot tem seu próprio *servlet container* (Tomcat por padrão) e tudo o que precisa para "deployar a si próprio e se inicializar sozinho", basta um ponto de entrada (o método `main()`) para que ele seja executado.

É diferente de uma aplicação feita em Spring MVC, por exemplo, em que você precisa indicar um Tomcat externo (e que já esteja pré-instalado), startar você mesmo esse contâiner para só então executar sua aplicação. Isso sem contar toda a configuração "na mão" que você vai precisar fazer para tornar seu projeto funcional.

E aí você pergunta, mas por que o Spring MVC não segue esse mesmo conceito de inicialização?

O primeiro ponto é que o Spring MVC é uma implementação da Servlet API do Java EE (interface para sistemas web) com (muitas) vantagens e facilidades para o desenvolvimento. E qualquer implementação da Servlet API precisa de um servidor de aplicação (Tomcat, JBoss, Glassfish etc.) para rodar, com toda a "burocracia" de configuração e inicialização envolvida.

O segundo ponto é que, por baixo dos panos, o Spring Boot tem o Spring MVC (afinal, o Boot continua a ser um framework de desenvolvimento de sistema web), mas com a "burocracia" convenientemente automatizada o máximo possível.

Mas, e aí vem o grande mas, o Spring Boot foi pensado já levando em conta a arquitetura de microsserviços distribuída, em outras palavras, pequenos sistemas autoexecutáveis (olha a necessidade do método `main()` aí) e escaláveis que devem independer de servidor de aplicação centralizado para serem executados, startados, "matados" quando necessário, substituídos e redeployados. Esse tipo de microsserviço, na verdade, deve se comportar como uma aplicação desktop, isolada e autossuficiente, com a menor quantidade de dependência externa possível. Essas características não são encontradas num projeto Spring MVC, mas foram elas que tornaram o Spring Boot tão popular e tão utilizado no mundo todo.